# Speeding up matrix exponentiation using openmp

Tags: c, multithreading, matrix, optimization, openmp

I have a function that computes the n-th power of a matrix using power. The code is written in C:

```
void matrix_power(matrix *result, matrix *mat, int pow) {
    if (pow == 0) {
        for (int r = 0; r < mat->rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < mat->cols; c++) {
                result->content[r][c] = r == c;
            }
        }
    } else if (pow == 1) {
        for (int r = 0; r < mat->rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < mat->cols; c++) {
                result->content[r][c] = mat->content[r][c];
            }
        }
    } else {
        matrix *temp;
        copy_matrix(temp, mat); //now temp becomes mat
        matrix_power(temp, mat, pow /= 2);
        matrix_multiply(result, temp, temp);
        if (pow % 2 == 1) {
            copy_matrix(temp, result);
            matrix_multiply(result, temp, mat);
        }
        deallocate_matrix(temp);
    }
}
```

I want to optimize my code so it's 1000 times faster than the naive implementation of matrix powering. Currently my implementation is only 300 times faster. My matrix_multiply function has been decently optimized using SIMD and openMP. I want to use openMP to achieve better parallel performance. How can I do that? Or is there any other methods I should consider to reap a significant speed boost?

Comment: Is the matrix diagonalizable?

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to mention that the the the entries of the matrix are double's. So I guess diagonalizing it will be difficult.

Comment: Should `pow /= 2` be `pow / 2`?

Comment: `matrix *temp;` followed by `copy_matrix(temp, mat);` looks like it is using an invalid (uninitialized) pointer value from `temp`. Unless `copy_matrix` is a macro that does something non-functionlike.

Comment: @V.Reeve I don't know why you are guessing that it is difficult due to doubles. What harold means is that in the really interesting cases (big matrices/big powers) one would rather diagnonalize the matrix (which means transforming the matrix into it's eigenspace representation), do the calculation and transform back. He might also have only read the title of your question and thought that you meant exp(matrix) instead of matrix^number. For actual matrix exponentiation exp(matrix), diagonalization is mostly unavoidable.

Comment: Also given that you have already parallelized the matrix multiplication, it doesn't make any sense to try to parallelize this function. The multiplication should contain most of the work done in this function, so there is nothing more to do.